# How to call two servers in a single spec helper file

Tags: rspec, watir-webdriver, rspec2, rspec-rails, rspec3

Currently i am automating a feature using Watir-webdriver with Rspec. Here am using two different servers, first i need to open a server and then need to do few steps after that i need to open the second server and need to perform few steps.Here i have two different spec helper files which has config.before :all(will invoke the server and perform all the login things) and config.after :all (Will close the browsers).I need to Integrate both the spechelper in a single file.Please help me once after the config.before:all executes and finishes the steps how can i call the second server?

Comment: A code example of what you have tried and where you are having problems might help you get answers. At the moment, it is hard to visualize what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

@Watir -- what do you mean by 'call two servers' or 'open a server'?

If you mean 'create two browsers', that's pretty easy:

```ruby
before(:all) do
  @b1 = Watir::Browser.new
  @b2 = Watir::Browser.new
  # ...
end
```

If instead you mean that you want to use Server1 to initiate watir-webdriver actions on Server2 and Server3, that is most commonly done with [Grid2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) as demonstrated here by [markoh.co.uk](http://markoh.co.uk/posts/running-webdriver-tests-locally-vs-remotely):

```ruby
before(:all) do
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
  capabilities.browser_name = :firefox

  @b1 = Watir::Browser.new( 
      :remote, 
      :url => "http://<server IP>:4444/wd/hub", 
      :desired_capabilities => capabilities
  )

  @b2 = Watir::Browser.new( 
      :remote, 
      :url => "http://<server IP>:4444/wd/hub", 
      :desired_capabilities => capabilities
  )
end
```

Note that Grid must be configured on the remote server.